# Laravel nova restrict viewAny()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

When I want users not to be able to enter an individual resource I can use policies to do the following:

```
public function view(User $user, Model $object)
{
    if($user->groupName != $object->groupName) {
       return false;
    } else {
       return true;
    }
}
```

This has as a result that the Components of your group have the eye icon (see red cirle). Components I do not want the user to see dont have the eye icon.

[image: Result]

**My desired result is that the `should not be seen` component is not shown at all. How can I achieve this?**

I tried:

```
public function viewAny(User $user)
{
     // $object does not exist here so I cannot use it to filter
     if($user->groupName == $object->groupName) {
       return true;
    } else {
       return false;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Basically my problem is the following: returning false from a policy's view method does not stop the resource from appearing in the resource index

Comment: Can you also show the code of your controller that fetches the data

Comment: Because i want to suggest to try updating your code that fetches the data from the db. Something like this: `User::where('userIsAdmin', true)->get();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the index query of your resource. [see more](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/resources/authorization.html#index-filtering)

```
public static function indexQuery(NovaRequest $request, $query)
{
    return $query->where('groupName', $request->user()->group_name);
}
```

You should consider updating the relateble query too.

Comment: Thank you, your link seems to be broken though